# Create a new link stye in Typo3?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Is there a way to add a new style to the Insert Link dialog in Typo3?
Currently they are "internal-link", "internal-link-new-window", or no style.

I have tried putting various things in the Page tsconfig with no results at all...

I found this on another site which looks like it does what I want but I can't get it to do anything:

```
RTE.classesAnchor {
  tollerLink1 {
    class = button
    type = page
    titleText = Button
  }
}

RTE.default {
  classesAnchor:=addToList(button)
}
```

Comment: yes it is... https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/rtehtmlarea/DefaultConfigurations/Typical/Index.html

Comment: @biesior How do you edit/where do you find that part of tsconfig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your TsConfig (Home Page Properties - Resources - Page TSConfig)

```
RTE.default.buttons {
link.properties.class.allowedClasses := addToList(internal-link-new-window)
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do a similar thing but to add a custom Image Position Option?